# Sort json keys in objects that are inside the array

Tags: javascript, json

How can I sort the keys inside the object that is inside an array?

So I have a json file that has this data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "age": 17,
    "location": "US"
  },
  {
    "age": 15,
    "name": "BBB",
    "location": "CA"
  },
  {
    "location": "NZ",
    "age": 10,
    "name": "CCC"
  }, ...
 ]
```

How can I possibly make the data like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "age": 17,
    "location": "US"
  },
  {
    "name": "BBB",
    "age": 15,
    "location": "CA"
  },
  {
  
    "name": "CCC",
    "age": 10,
    "location": "NZ"
  }, ...
 ]
```

Comment: Why is this tagged typescript?

Comment: Why would you need to? The property order cannot be guaranteed in JS. Not in all implementations. But the main point is that it's irrelevant. If you want, for display purposes, to order them in a particular way, make an array of key-value pairs and sort it. That will guarantee the position is kept.

Comment: One helper you could use is `_.pick()` from lodash. The returned objects will have the same order as in the props array: `_.pick(data, ['name', 'age', 'location'])`.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. To learn more about SO best practices, check out the help section, particularly [ask]. As a side-note, I suggest you delete this question, which will get your rep back. My guess is it got down-voted because you haven't tried anything and, in general, it looks like you didn't research much. I, for one, think it's a good question to ask. But still, you could have made a bit of research and post the results of that research (and why it didn't help). Happy coding!

Comment: @tao The question is off-topic: "Don't ask about...

Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" [tour]

Comment: To be completely honest, I've tried a lot and it may have not seem like I did because of how I formulated my question. Thanks for caring about the reps but I really care about the answers and this might help someone else.

Comment: @tao Sorry, I didn't want to be offensive. Maybe I misunderstood _"I, for one, think it's a good question to ask."_  wrong. I interpreted it as _"it's a good question to ask on Stack Overflow"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can sort the props of each object.

1. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to modify its items
2. Use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert its `prop: value` pairs into an array so you could sort them
3. Convert them back to an object using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

The advantage of using this approach is that you don't need to know the prop names in advance.

```js
const source = [
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "age": 17,
    "location": "US"
  },
  {
    "age": 15,
    "name": "BBB",
    "location": "CA"
  },
  {
    "location": "NZ",
    "age": 10,
    "name": "CCC"
  }
 ]

const sortedSource = source.map(item => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).sort(([key1], [key2]) => {
      return key1.localeCompare(key2);
    })
  )
});

const stringify = obj => JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
console.log(stringify(source), stringify(sortedSource));
```

https://jsbin.com/fiwuyecuco/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you!!! This completely fixed it.

Comment: I wonder why you need this? In javascript the props order doesn't matter..

Answer (score 0):

The keys here do not seem to be sorted in either ascending or descending lexicographic order. However, they do have one common arrangement of keys as: name, age, location for every object.

For your specific case, one quick solution could be to use something like:

```
// say, array = [{...}, {...}, ...] is your given array of objects

array.forEach( (object, index) => { 
    array[index] = { "name":object.name, "age":object.age, "location":object.location }; 
} );
```

Following this, all objects within your array of objects should get arranged as desired.

Also, in case sorted keys order is desired, then `Object.keys(array[0]).sort()` order could be used within the forEach function given, as:

```
// say, array = [{...}, {...}, ...] is your given array of objects

sortedKeys = Object.keys(array[0]);

array.forEach( (object, index) => { 
    array[index] = {};
    for (key of sortedKeys)
        array[index][key] = object[key]
} );
```

Suggestions and improvements to the answer are welcome!